# Joomla, How to disable the “Flash Uploader”

Tags: php, flash, joomla, uploader

Please masters I'm new to joomla. How to disable the “Flash Uploader” in **version 1.5.0** ?

it seems that this option doesn’t exist in the global configuration !

Could you please suggest me any PHP lines to solve it ? Thanks a million.

[image]

Comment: You should update your Joomla version. This option exists in the media manager options.

Comment: I can't update my joomla version !

Answer (score 0):

There are no option available as Joomla 1.5.26 and never have to disable **flash uploader**. IF you don't want to use **flash uploader** then you restrict the user to use this in your Joomla 1.5.0.
For doing this here's the navigation:

Global Configuration -> System Tab -> Under the media settings -> disable the **Restrict Uploads**

[image]

Comment: This is the problem, in my version I can't have the "System Tab"

Comment: Then which version are you using ?

Comment: what do you mean "I can't have the system tab"? You don't have access to it?

Comment: No I have acces but the tab dosen't exist in Version 1.5.0 (Please see the capture)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQGIL.png

Comment: Did you change any core files? Because i don't know why it's not showing ,I have the Joomla 1.5.0 version and it have that tabs in it.

Comment: No I didn't, and this what is shown in media setting http://i.stack.imgur.com/pnAU1.png

Comment: Ok set this `Transferts Restreients` to `no` and it will restrict user to upload the files.

Comment: There is no way in the world you should have a 1.5.0 site on the internet, there are major security issues and anyone coudl go to youtube and see how to gain control of your site in about 15 minutes.